# Exporting Tiled maps on Eclipse with Libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

i'm having some problems loading the levels of a project i'm doing. I already put the .tmx files and the .png images from the level on the "Assets" folder but i keep having this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: Downloads/simpleGraphics_tiles16x16.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:96)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:84)
at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:65)
at com.proyecto.game.Screens.PlayScreen.<init>(PlayScreen.java:28)
at com.proyecto.game.MainMenuScreen.MainMenuScreen.render(MainMenuScreen.java:57)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.proyecto.game.miProject.render(miProject.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:225)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: 
Downloads\simpleGraphics_tiles16x16.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:144)
... 11 more
```

I'm using also this call the map:

```
    maploader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = maploader.load("Nivel1.tmx");
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
```

What can be causing the error?

Comment: Please show your .Tmx file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tmx` file having entry of your `.png` file. You kept `.tmx` file  inside Assets with all associated `.png` but you not edited path in `.tmx` file

May be you've entry in `.tmx` entry like this :

```
<image source="Downloads\simpleGraphics_tiles16x16.png" width="64" height="64"/>
```

so change it to :

```
<image source="simpleGraphics_tiles16x16.png" width="64" height="64"/>
```

I assume `simpleGraphics_tiles16x16.png` and `.tmx` file are in same folder inside Assets.

Comment: Yes, both are in the same folder. It worked now fine. Another question is there any way i can "zoom in" or make more bigger the way i see the level on the window? EDIT: I figure it out how now :)